# How to triangulate real projective spaces (as simplicial complexes in Mathematica)?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, homology

Hello!

I have written a program in Mathematica 7, which calculates for a (finite abstract) simplicial complex all its homology groups. I would really like to test it on the projective spaces, but cannot find a way to triangulate them. There seem to be very few articles on this matter and none of them states directly how the actual triangulations might be achieved, so I turn to MO for help.

**How can the real projective spaces
$$RP^n \approx B^n/_{x\:\sim-x;\;\; x\in\partial B^n}$$
be triangulated as simplicial complexes?** A simplicial complex is presented as a list of simplices that aren't a face of any bigger simplex (the "main simplices"). Each k-simplex is just an ordered list of some k+1 integers.

For example, {0,1,2} is a 2-simplex, as is {1,3,15}, etc. Examples of simplicial complexes: {{0,...,n}} is a n-dimensional ball, {{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}} is an empty triangle, skeleton[{Range[n+2]},n] is a n-sphere, etc.

I have already found a concrete triangulation for the real projective plane, but nothing more general.

It would also be **appreciated, that the actual triangulation is reasonably small** (not necessarily minimal), so that the program calculates homology groups fast enough. Also, **answers in code / pseudocode are much desirable** (projectiveSpace[n_]:=???).

P.S. I have already written some functions, which can be used (sc...simplicial complex):

1. skeleton[sc,k] ...list of all k-faces of all simplices
2. sum[sc1,sc2]...topological sum (disjoint union)
3. connected sum[sc1,sc2] ...removes two k-simplicices and adds a tunnel between them
4. product[sc1,sc2]...staircase triangulation of a product (reorders the vertices)
5. cone[sc]
6. suspension[sc]

Comment: What are your $B^n$?

Comment: Ball of dimension n.

Comment: There are some interesting simplicial complexes on this page that you might play around with, though I don't see any with the topology of RP^3 http://infoshako.sk.tsukuba.ac.jp/~hachi/math/library/index_eng.html 

Comment: RP^2 is obtained from the regular icosahedron by identifying opposite points.  Have you tried looking at higher dimensional regular polyhedra?

Comment: @Steven, regular polyhedra get scarce waaaaay too fast as the dimension grows :) 

Comment: John Palmieri at U Washington has recently implemented these same calculations in Sage. I suggest you send him an email. 

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez But you still have hyperoctahedra in each dimension, right? They do give cell structures with $d+1$ vertices and $2^d$ highest dimensional cells, closure of each of the latter an embedded closed $d$-simplex (with all faces distinct)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want code, see the patch for Sage at http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/attachment/ticket/9125/trac_9125-projective-space.patch.  This patch also includes references for triangulations of $\mathbf{R}P^n$, but I'll summarize the results here, too.  For $n=3$, every triangulation must have at least 11 vertices, and the code gives an 11-vertex triangulation as described by Lutz in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506372.  For $n=4$, every triangulation must have at least 16 vertices, and the code gives such a triangulation, also given by Lutz.

For $n>4$, I think that no minimal examples are known, or at least they weren't a year ago.  But to get a triangulation of $\mathbf{R}P^n$, take the $n$-sphere as $\partial \Delta^{n+1}$, the boundary of an $(n+1)$-simplex.  Barycentrically subdivide once; the resulting complex $K$ is still a sphere, but with vertices in one-to-one correspondence with the non-empty faces of $\partial \Delta^{n+1}$, which is to say in one-to-one correspondence with the nonempty proper subsets of $T= (0, 1, 2, ..., n+1)$.  (I'm not sure why I can't get curly braces to show up here...).  This triangulation $K$ of the sphere has a simplicial $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$-action: on vertices (which correspond to nonempty proper subsets of $T$), send the vertex corresponding to a set $S$ to the vertex corresponding to $T-S$.  The quotient space is a triangulation of $\mathbf{R}P^n$, with $2^{n+1}-1$ vertices.

Comment: Thank you for your time & effort. I will try to implement it in my Mathematica and I'll report how it went.

Answer (score 5):

(This should be a comment, but it is too long to be comfortably edited there)

According to a theorem of Arnoux and Marin [Arnoux, Pierre; Marin, Alexis. The Kühnel triangulation of the complex projective plane from the view point of complex crystallography. II. Mem. Fac. Sci. Kyushu Univ. Ser. A 45 (1991), no. 2, 167--244. [MR1133113](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1133113))], a triangulation of $\mathbb RP^d$ has at least $(d+1)(d+2)/2$ vertices. Triangulations were explicitely constructucted by Kühnel [Kühnel, W. Minimal triangulations of Kummer varieties. Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg 57 (1987), 7--20. [MR0927159](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0927159), with $2^{d+1}-1$ vertices and $\frac12(d+1)!$ simplices.

Having lower bounds for the number of vertices $n$, makes it useful to know that there exist lower and upper bounds for the $f$-vectors (*i.e.*, for the number of simplices) in terms of $d$ and $n$. Two nice ones are those of Kalai and Gromov for a lower bound ([MR0877009](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0877009))], and of Novik for an upper bound ([MR1669325](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1669325)).

Our fellow MOer Gil could probably tell us about the state of the art :)

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find my mistake and here is the final (if I'm not mistaken) correct solution.

```
ClearAll[faces, skeleton, subseteq, subset, sBarycentricSubdivision, \
scBarycentricSubdivision, sphere, projectiveSpace]
faces[s_, k_] := Reverse@Subsets[s, {k + 1}]
skeleton[sc_, k_] := Union[Sort /@ Flatten[faces[#, k] & /@ sc, 1]]

subseteq[{},A_List] := True
subseteq[{x_,y___}, A_List] := MemberQ[A, x] && subset[{y}, A]
subseteq[A_List,B_List, C__List] := subset[A,B] && subset[B,C]
subset[A_List, B_List] := subseteq[A, B] && Complement[B, A]!={}
subset[A_List, B_List, C__List] := subset[A, B] && subset[B, C]

sBarycentricSubdivision[{x_Integer}] := {{{x}}}
sBarycentricSubdivision[s_List] := 
 Subsets[s, {1, Length@s}] //Subsets[#,{Length@s}]& //
  Select[#,subset@@#&]& 
scBarycentricSubdivision[sc_List] := 
 Flatten[sBarycentricSubdivision /@ sc, 1]

sphere[n_Integer]  := skeleton[{Range[n+2]},n]

projectiveSpace[n_Integer] := Module[
  {sc1, vertices1, k, identification, sc2, vertices2, sc3},
  sc1 = scBarycentricSubdivision[sphere[n]];
  vertices1 = 
   Sort@DeleteDuplicates@
     Flatten[sc1, 
      1]; (*the vertices (lists) are ordered antipodally with respect \
to complement, ie. vertices1[i]={1,...,n+2}-vertices1[-i]*)
  k = Length@vertices1;
  identification = 
   Table[vertices1[[-i]] -> vertices1[[i]], {i, 1, k/2}];
  sc2 = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ (sc1/.identification)];
  vertices2 = Flatten[sc2, 1] //Sort //DeleteDuplicates;
  sc3 = Map[Position[vertices2, #][[1, 1]] &, sc2, {2}] //Sort //
    DeleteDuplicates;
  sc3
  ]
```

And now, the command projectiveSpace[2] indeed returns a triangulation of the projective plane with 7 vertices and 12 faces. Also, the homology groups of $RP^0$,..., $RP^3$ all seem to be correct.

Thank you, mr. Palmieri, greetings from Slovenia.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've managed to write the whole thing, but it doesn't work quite right. Here is the code (s...simplex, sc...simplicial complex):

```
ClearAll[faces, skeleton, subseteq, subset,
barycentricSubdivisionOfSimplex, barycentricSubdivision, sphere,
projectiveSpace]
faces[s_, k_] := Reverse@Subsets[s, {k + 1}]
skeleton[sc_, k_] := Union[Sort /@ Flatten[faces[#, k] & /@ sc, 1]]

subseteq[{}, A_List] := True
subseteq[{x_, y___}, A_List] := MemberQ[A, x] && subset[{y}, A]
subseteq[A_List, B_List, C__List] := subset[A, B] && subset[B, C]
subset[A_List, B_List] := subseteq[A, B] && Complement[B, A] != {}
subset[A_List, B_List, C__List] := subset[A, B] && subset[B, C]

barycentricSubdivisionOfSimplex[{x_Integer}] := {{{x}}}
barycentricSubdivisionOfSimplex[s_List] := 
 Subsets[s, {1, Length@s}] // Subsets[#, {Length@s}] & // 
  Select[#, subset @@ # &] & 
barycentricSubdivision[sc_List] := 
 Flatten[barycentricSubdivisionOfSimplex /@ sc, 1]

sphere[n_Integer]  := skeleton[{Range[n + 2]}, n]

projectiveSpace[n_Integer] := Module[{sc1, sc2, vertices, sc3},
  sc1 = barycentricSubdivision[sphere[n]];
  sc2 = Map[
    Which[Length[#] <= Quotient[n + 2, 2], #, True, 
      Complement[Range[n + 2], #]] &, sc1, {2}];
  vertices = Flatten[sc2, 1] // Sort // DeleteDuplicates;
  sc3 = Sort /@ Map[Position[vertices, #][[1, 1]] &, sc2, {2}] // 
     Sort // DeleteDuplicates;
  Which[n == 0, {{1}}, True, sc3]
  ]
```

I basically followed the instructions of mr. Palmieri. The problem is, that the homology of my projectiveSpace[n] for n=0,...,4 returns

```
{{1}, {{}}}
{{1, 1}, {{}, {}}}
{{1, 0, 3}, {{}, {2}, {}}}
{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {{}, {2}, {}, {}}}
{{1, 0, 0, 0, 10}, {{}, {2}, {}, {2}, {}}}
```

which is obviously incorrect for n=2,4 (the first list represents the betti numbers, the second the torsion coefficients). However, quite a few betti numbers and torsion coefficients seem to be correct, so I'm guessing the error is minor.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I intended to accept it right after the solution was fully developed, but at this stage, the code still doesn't work properly. I accepted as you suggested, but I still seek a working code in Mathematica...

Comment: I don't know Mathematica syntax, so I can't really follow your code. You should try to list the vertices and the facets for your version of RP^2 and try to figure out what the problem is.  I believe that if it's working right, you should have 7 vertices and 12 facets for RP^2.
